# Does TCP duplicate ACKs acknowledge the correct packet received?

Tags: networking, tcp

As shown below, at step 7, when the receiver sends ACK (16) to the sender while the correct ACK is (18), does the sender take that as an ACK for packet(17)? If not, do we need to retransmit SEQ:17 to SEQ:19?

```
Sender              Receiver

1: SEQ:15       ->
2: SEQ:16       ->  (dropped)
3: SEQ:17       ->
4: SEQ:18       ->
5: SEQ:19       ->
6:              <-     ACK:16       (for SEQ:15 packet)
7:              <-     ACK:16   (for SEQ:17 packet) 
8:              <-     ACK:16
9:              <-     ACK:16
10: SEQ:16      ->
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. It takes it as an ACK for 16 and everything that *preceded* it.

Taking it as an ACK for something after what it is ACKing doesn't begin to make sense.

Any data that isn't ACKed should be retransmitted.

Comment: so, SEQ:17, to SEQ:19 should be retransmitted too? It doesn't seem to be right. From what I understand, after SEQ:16 retransmission, receiver will ACK highest saved SEQ which in this case would be ACK:20(for SEQ:19 packet). Am I getting it right?